# In python grpc I got a exception “No match found for server name”

Tags: python, grpc

I create key with this command:

```
openssl req -newkey rsa:2048 -nodes -keyout server.key -x509 -days 365 -out server.crt
```

My server code:

```
server_credentials = grpc.ssl_server_credentials(((_private_key, _certificate_chain,),))

server = grpc.server(futures.ThreadPoolExecutor(max_workers=MAX_THREADPOOL_EXECUTOR))
server.add_secure_port('[::]:{0}'.format(AGENT_PORT), server_credentials)
server.add_insecure_port('[::]:{0}'.format(AGENT_PORT))

print("AgentServicer start at port {}...".format(AGENT_PORT))
server.start()
try:
    while True:
        # we can do something in main thread......
        time.sleep(_ONE_DAY_IN_SECONDS)
except KeyboardInterrupt:
    server.stop(0)
```

My client code:

```
credentials = grpc.ssl_channel_credentials(root_certificates=_certificate_chain)
channel = grpc.secure_channel('{}:{}'.format("localhost", 10010), credentials)

# channel = grpc.insecure_channel('{}:{}'.format("localhost", 10010))
stub = agent_pb2_grpc.AgentStub(channel)
response = stub.GetAgentVersion(agent_pb2.NoParams())
print("GreeterService client received: " + response.version)
```

I get an exception:

```
No match found for server name
```

What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 13, accepted):

I suspect that your server certificate does not have `CN=localhost` which you are trying to connect from your client. In that case, you need to either create your server certificate to include such `Common Name`, or from your client you need to connect to the name that exist in your certificate.